# How do I scp a file from server A to server B from cron?

Tags: ssh, scripting, cron, password, scp

I have a file in server A which I am able to do transfer to server B using scp. 
I need to do this through a cron entry. server B has a password.
How do I perform this?

Comment: Here's a short but complete reference, including permission settings: http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use password authentication. Use ssh keypairs.

```
Karthik@A $: ssh-keygen    #keep the passphrase empty
Karthik@A $: ssh-copy-id B #enter your B password
#^ this will copy your public key to Karthik@B:.ssh/authorized_keys
```

From then on, you should be able to ssh from **A** to **B** (and by extension, `scp` from **A** to **B**) without a password.

Comment: And, for extra security, you can [restrict the commands that the key is allowed to run](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214283/should-the-key-for-an-automatically-running-cron-job-that-runs-over-ssh-not-have), and even [what directories it can access with scp](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9853/restricting-an-ssh-scp-sftp-user-to-a-directory).

Comment: is there a detailed document from where I can follow the steps. I'm new to unix.

Answer (score 0):

Generate an ssh-key on server A using ssh-keygen.  This will generate a private and public key pair in `$HOME/.ssh`.  Add the public key to the `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on server B.

You can use the `man` command to get more information.  The command `man authorized_keys` will present the manual page that discusses authorized keys.

Try the following sites for discussions:

- Ubuntu [SSH/OpenSSH/Keys](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys)
- ServerFault [Simple SSH public/private key question](https://serverfault.com/questions/215546/simple-ssh-public-private-key-question)
- DigitalOcean [How To Set Up SSH Keys](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2)

Comment: is there a detailed document from where I can follow the steps. I'm new to unix.

Comment: @Karthik See links above.